# Photoshop adding background layer to my cut and paste

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

When I cut and paste part of an image to a new file I am getting a back ground layer that is slightly larger than the size of the image.

How do I prevent Photoshop adding a background layer or at least make it the same size as the image dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

To my knowledge, there's always a background layer in Photoshop, but you can remove it by double-clicking it and dragging it in the little trash on the bottom of the layers panel.

**2.**

Regarding the slightly larger background, It could be caused by your selection having a "feather" on it.

[image: SELECTION WITH AND WITHOUT FEATHER]

When you select something with a feather value, you new Photoshop file where you will paste the image you copied will be slightly bigger because of this.

> **Try setting the feather to 0 and see if it still does this.**

[image: Feather in Adobe Photoshop]

Comment: oh it did have a feather! thanks for helping!